# Sench Touch 2 - Rendering a List

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a simple MVC Sencha Touch application, with 1 store, 2 models and 2 views - a toolbar and a list. My toolbar renders fine, but the list does not. No exception is thrown and I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

The store (Books.js):

```
Ext.define('App.store.Books', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'App.model.Book',
    autoLoad: true,
    data: [
    { id: '1', name: '1984', publisher: 'Orwell' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Biography',  publisher: 'abcde' },
    { id: '3', name: 'The Old Man and the Sea',  publisher: 'Hemingway' }
    ]
});
```

The view (List.js - I have another Bar.js which renders fine):

```
Ext.define('App.view.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    store : 'Books',
    xtype : 'mylist',
    itemTpl: '<div><strong>Name: {name}</strong>Publisher: {publisher}</div>'
});
```

The viewport (Viewport.js) - extends Ext.Container as I saw in several examples:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires : [
        'App.view.Bar',
        'App.view.List'
    ],
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
        {
            xtype : 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'mylist'
        }
        ]
    }
});
```

As I wrote - my toolbar is shown, my list ('mylist') isn't.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a config to your view

```
Ext.define('App.view.List', {

    extend:    'Ext.List',
    config:    {

        title:   'Books',
        cls:     'books',
        store:   'Books',
        itemTpl: '<div><strong>Name: {name}</strong>Publisher: {publisher}</div>'

    }

});
```